# How to collate a Dataset that might return different size encoding at every index?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader, huggingface

I want to apply a random augmentation transformation inside a Dataset and it may return encoding of different sizes at every index. Different size of encodings is produced by a processor from huggingface. How do I handle the dataset so that I get mini-batches of constant batch size while iterating using a dataloader?

Below is a snippet where I have put dummy variables to explain my case:

```
from datasets import Dataset
import torch

class DummyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        # Each list of list in `x` encodings is an example output from a huggingface processor. This will be lazily generated in __getitem__ while reading millions of files from the disk. 
        self.x = [
            [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],
            [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], 
            [[0, 1, 2]]
            ]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return torch.Tensor(self.x[idx])
    
    
    

dataset = DummyDataset()    

from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=1, )



for minibatch in dataloader:
    print(minibatch)

"""
Actual Output: 

tensor([[[0., 1., 2.],
         [3., 4., 5.],
         [6., 7., 8.]]])
tensor([[[0., 1., 2.],
         [3., 4., 5.]]])
tensor([[[0., 1., 2.]]])
"""

"""
Expected Output when batchsize is 1:

tensor([[0, 1, 2]])
tensor([[3, 4, 5]])
tensor([[6, 7, 8]])
tensor([[0, 1, 2]])
tensor([[3, 4, 5]])
tensor([[0, 1, 2]])

"""
"""
Expected Output when batchsize is 2:

tensor([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]])
tensor([[6, 7, 8], [0, 1, 2]])
tensor([[3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2]])


"""
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand it, but is `x` when you initialize your DummyDataset? In this case, you could flatten your data:`self.x = [y for x in self.x for y in x]`

Comment: @cronoik - this is just a dummy variable I have defined. It will be lazily generated in __getitem__.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. How about: you randomly select in getitem and put the not selected elements into a property `y` (let's say a list). You also need a condition that checks if `y` contains elements, if so it should take those before generating new ones from the processor.